# gcloud functions package folder with .gcloudignore as a zip without upload it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-deployment-manager

I would like to compress and upload a cloud function to a bucket. But not deploy the function.

I am going to deploy it with a Deployment Manager
template: `type: 'gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions'`.

I can't find an option in gcloud cli to zip a folder and ignore files in `.gcloudignore` if I create the zip manually, something like `git archive`.

I read [google cloud functions command to package without deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364976/google-cloud-functions-command-to-package-without-deploying) but I don't know how to ignore the files if I create the zip manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Also, you can directly upload the zip to the bucket with `gcloud cp` if you already have it, have you tried doing so?

Comment: I am uploading the zip with `gsutil cp` but the main problem is create the zip and ignore files in `.gcloudignore`, for now I am ignoring files manual with `-x` modifier, but it isn't sync with `.gcloudignore` so I need to update both places when need to change ignored files.